# find which percentile group does a user belong to in mysql

Tags: mysql, group-by, window-functions, percentile

hope someone could help.
I have the following table
[image]

I now want to categorize users into 4 different groups which are <20th percentile,<40th percentile,<60th percentile,<80th percentile based on the GMV column.

so basically I want to add a column named Percentile_group and it would look something like this:

```
user_id    monthYear     gmv   percentile_group
 414       jan 2020     3168       40
 2257      jan 2020     1452       60
 .          .            .         .
 .          .            .         .
 .          .            .         .
```

I tried calculating the 4 percentiles and then compare values but the percentile values are wrong.

```
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( GROUP_CONCAT(gmv ORDER BY 
gmv SEPARATOR ','), ',', 50/100 * COUNT(*) + 1), ',', -1) AS DECIMAL) 
AS 50th_Per from table
```

Can someone help me out please?

Comment: [NTILE() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_ntile)

Comment: Which version of MySQL?  And, please don't use images to show sample data. Use text and indent it four spaces. Please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use `ntile()` for this:

```
select t.*, ntile(4) over(order by gmv) percentile_group
from mytable t
```

This creates four groups, from `1` to `4`, with `1` being the group with the lowest `gmv`s.